# How can i combine orthographic camera X, Y and the input processor screenX, screenY?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I made a two rectangles to divide screen in two regions. Touching in each region do two different things. my camera is like below:

```
camera = new OrthographicCamera();
camera.setToOrtho(false, 800, 480);
```

My rectangles are like these:

```
leftRectangle.set(0, 0, 400, 400);
rightRectangle.set(400, 0, 400, 400);
```

So what i thought i am doing with camera that, I made my phone screen resolution 800px 400px, whatever my actual resolution, it does not matter, coz i am using camera to do so. But inputprocessor screenX and screenY is returning X,Y according to my phones actual resolution. So I am not getting the camera made touching X,Y. So I am geeting wrong touching value.

How can i make this touching X,Y value same as the camera made resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Camera.unproject()`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Camera.html#unproject%28com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3%29) to do that.

```
Vector3 screenCoords = new Vector3(screenX, screenY, 1);
Vector3 cameraCoords = camera.uproject(screenCoords);
float cameraX = cameraCoords.x;
float cameraY = cameraCoords.y;
```